# Cannot download security updates in Lubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: security, downloads

Software Updater offers Security Updates--Ubuntu Base--61.9MB. I click Install now and authenticate. Screen shows "Failed to download package, check your internet connection'. There is no problem with my internet connection that I am aware of. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is the output of?: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Thank you @xangua, another attempt proved successful, but I will keep your link, do I input everything after 'of' ?